# SwiperJS not sliding over iFrame

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, nuxt.js, swiper.js

I have implemented Swiper in NuxtJs. I have to embed ads in the form of iFrame in slides. But my swiper stuck at iFrame. It is not sliding over the iframe.
I have tried adding scrolling='no' to the iframe, but it didn't work.
Also I want to hit the events of the iframe

My Code

````
      new Swiper(this.$refs.swiper, {
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        spaceBetween: 20,
        centeredSlidesBounds: true,
        centerInsufficientSlides: true,
        watchSlidesProgress: true,
        watchSlidesVisibility: true,
        direction: 'horizontal',
        mousewheel: true,
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true,
        freeMode: true,
        parallax: true,
        initialSlide: slideNumber,
        keyboard: {
          enabled: true
        },
        scrollbar: {
          el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
          draggable: true
        },
        loopFillGroupWithBlank: false,
        pagination: {
          clickable: true
        },
        autoHeight: true,
        modules: 'modules',
        on: {
          activeIndexChange: function (swiper) {
            vm.listenAds()
            setTimeout(() => {
              swiper.params.centeredSlides = true
              swiper.update()
            }, 100)
          },
          afterInit: function (swiper) {
            setInterval(() => {
              swiper.update()
            }, 100)
          }
        }

      })
    }```
````

Comment: Yeah this sounds unlikely, as iframes capture all the events and you do not receive them on your page in that case. So either disable all events on it (`pointer-events: none`) or live with the fact that you cant swipe on an iframe for the sliding on the parent page...

Comment: Also, do you have a [repro]?